# cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘2’

Tags: c, floating-point

I am having trouble figuring this out to get a netpay to display. For the assignment I have to have an external function. I keep this:

> calcTax.cpp: In function ‘void calculateTaxes(float, float, float*, float*, float*, float*)’:
>
> calcTax.cpp:61:56: error: cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘float calcNet(float, float*, float*, float*, float)’
>
> *totNet = calcNet(gross,*fedtax,*statetax,*ssitax,defr);

I'm pretty new to coding in general, so any help would be great. The first piece is the external and the second in the main file.

```
#define FEDTAXRATE 0.15
#define STATETAXRATE 0.07
#define SSITAXRATE 0.0775

float calcFedTax(float gross, float defr);
float calcStateTax(float fedtax);
float calcSSITax(float gross,float defr);
float calcNet(float gross, float *fedtax, float *statetax, float *ssitax,float defr);
void calculateTaxes(float gross,float defr,float *fedtax,float *statetax,float *ssitax,float$
{
        *fedtax = calcFedTax(gross,defr);
        *statetax = calcStateTax(*fedtax);
        *ssitax = calcSSITax(gross,defr);
        *totNet = calcNet(gross,*fedtax,*statetax,*ssitax,defr);
}
float calcFedTax(float gross,float defr)
{
        return(gross - defr) * FEDTAXRATE;
}
float calcStateTax(float fedtax)
{
        return fedtax * STATETAXRATE;
}
float calcSSITax(float gross,float defr)
{
        return(gross-defr) * SSITAXRATE;
}
float calcNet(float gross, float *fedtax, float *statetax, float *ssitax,float defr)
{
        return(gross - *fedtax - *statetax - *ssitax - defr);
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FEDTAXRATE .15
#define STATETAXRATE .07
#define SSITAXRATE .0775
#define ADDR(var) &(var)
void PrintReportHeading(FILE *reportfile);
void getEmployeeInput(char firstname[],char lastname[],float * Reg,float * payrate,float *defr);
float calculateGross(float Reg,float payrate);
float calculateNet(float gross,float defr,float ft,float st,float ssit);
extern void calculateTaxes(float gross,float defr,float *fedtax,float *statetax,float *ssitax);
void addDetailToAccumulators(float payrate,float Ovt,float Reg,float gross,float ft,float st,float ssit,
                float defr,float Net,float *totRate,float *totOvt,float *totReg,float *totGross,float *totFed,
                float *totState,float *totSSI,float *totDefr,float *totNet);
void printSummaryReport(char lastname[], char firstname[],FILE *reportfile, float payrate, float Reg, float gross,
                                                float ft, float ssit, float Net, float st, float defr, float Ovt);
int main(void)
{
        char lastname[15+1];
    char firstname[10+1];
    float hours=0, payrate=0, defr=0, gross=0, ft=0, st=0, ssit=0, Ovt=0, Reg=0, Net=0, totReg=0,
                totDefr=0, totOvt=0, totNet=0, totState=0, totRate=0, totGross=0, totFed=0, totSSI;

        FILE * reportfile;
    reportfile = fopen("./report.lst","wt");
    if (reportfile == NULL)
    {
      printf("  Report file open failed ...\n");
      while (getchar() != '\n');
      exit(-100);
    }
        PrintReportHeading(reportfile);
        getEmployeeInput(lastname,firstname,ADDR(Reg),ADDR(payrate),ADDR(defr)); //3.3
        gross = calculateGross(Reg,payrate); //call 3.4
        Net = calculateNet(gross,defr,ft,st,ssit);
        calculateTaxes(gross,defr,ADDR(ft),ADDR(st),ADDR(ssit));
        addDetailToAccumulators(payrate, Ovt, Reg, gross, ft, st, ssit, defr, Net, ADDR(totRate), ADDR(totOvt), ADDR(totReg), ADDR(totFed), ADDR(totFed),ADDR(totState),
                    ADDR(totSSI),ADDR(totDefr),ADDR(totNet));
        printSummaryReport(firstname,lastname,reportfile,payrate,Reg,gross,ft,ssit,Net,st,defr,Ovt);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        return 0;
}
void PrintReportHeading(FILE *reportfile)
{
    fprintf(reportfile,"     Employee        Pay        RegHrs/     Gross      Fedtax      StateTax     Net\n");
    fprintf(reportfile,"     Name            Rate       OvtHrs      Pay        SSItax      Defr         Pay\n");
    fprintf(reportfile,"     ========        ======     ======      ======     ======      ========     ======\n");
}
void getEmployeeInput(char *firstname,char *lastname,float *Reg,float *payrate,float *defr)
{
        printf("Enter the employee's first name ===> \n");
        scanf("%s", firstname);
        printf("Enter the employee's last name ===> \n");
        scanf("%s", lastname);
        printf("Enter the hours worked this pay period ===> \n");
        scanf("%f", Reg);
        printf("Enter the hourly payrate ===> \n");
        scanf("%f", payrate);
        printf("Enter the deferred earnings ===> \n");
        scanf("%f", defr);
}
float calculateGross(float Reg,float payrate)
{
        if (Reg <= 40)
                return Reg * payrate;
        else
                return 40 * payrate + 1.5*payrate*(Reg-40);
}
void addDetailToAccumulators(float payrate,float Ovt,float Reg,float Gross,float ft,float st,float ssit,
                float defr,float Net,float *totRate,float *totOvt,float *totReg,float *totGross,float *totFed,
                float *totState,float *totSSI,float *totDefr,float *totNet)
{
                *totRate  = *totRate  + payrate;
                *totOvt   = *totOvt   + Ovt;
                *totReg   = *totReg   + Reg;
                *totGross = *totGross + Gross;
                *totFed   = *totFed   + ft;
                *totState = *totState + st;
                *totSSI   = *totSSI   + ssit;
                *totDefr  = *totDefr  + defr;
                *totNet   = *totNet   + Net;
}
void printSummaryReport(char firstname[], char lastname[], FILE *reportfile, float payrate, float Reg, float gross,
                                                float ft, float st, float Ovt, float ssit, float defr, float Net)
{
        fprintf(reportfile,"%10s,%7s%8.2f%12.2f%12.2f%12.2f%12.2f%12.2f \n",firstname,lastname,payrate,Reg,gross,ft,st,Net);
        fprintf(reportfile,"                                                   %8.2f%17.2f \n",ssit,defr);
}
```

Comment: Can you decide whether this is supposed to be C or C++. I guess it's C.

Comment: If you don't know the difference of types `float` and `float*`, or what a pointer even is, you should read a C++ book.

Comment: Why are you using so many pointers unnecessarily? In `calcNet` `fedtax`, `statetax`, and `ssitax` are pointers but there is not benefit over passing by value.

Comment: the function calls out a pointer (float*) and you are feeding it a value (float)

Comment: @alden my professor really stressed decomposition so he wanted us to make a function for each task.

Comment: @nvoigt Well, there is `using namespace std;` in the code, so it is C++.

Comment: @XavierSperopoulos He wasn't questioning the use of functions. He was questioning the way you are passing arguments to the functions. You shouldn't pass parameters by pointer, when there is no benefit in doing so. Even then, C++ has references.

Answer (score 2):

The error is self-explanatory.  You are passing `float` values where the `calcNet()` function is expected `float*` pointers instead

Your `fedtax`, `statetax`, and `ssitax` parameters are already `float*` pointers to begin with, so just pass them as-is, do not dereference them, when passing them to `calcNet()`. IOW, change this:

```
*totNet = calcNet(gross,*fedtax,*statetax,*ssitax,defr);
```

to this:

```
*totNet = calcNet(gross,fedtax,statetax,ssitax,defr);
```

Comment: ive got it to run but it still isnt outputting the netpay

Comment: That should be posted as a new question then. This question is about a compiler error, which has been addressed. If your code is not behaving correctly when run, ask a new question about that.